# Joining multiple tables without any unique id for general search bar Laravel 7 giving sql error

Tags: laravel-7

I'm trying to make a general search bar which will fetch the related rows form 7 different tables but I am having problem in joining the 7 tables...
my code is

```
$query = $request->input('query');
$products = DB::table('manual_sellers')
    ->join('car_dealerships','manual_sellers.car_dealerships','=','')

        ->where('car_title' , 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('make', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('make', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('model', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('manufact_year', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('car_body', 'like', "%$query%")
    ->get();
```

when try to search then it throws error
[image: error]

how can I generally search a non unique value from 7 tables also appreciated if you have another good approach... because there will be tons of data to fetch in this query...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i would like to post the answer to help others...

```
$query = $request->input('query');
$products1 = DB::table('car_dealerships')
        ->where('car_title' , 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('make', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('model', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('manufact_year', 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('car_body', 'like', "%$query%")
->get();

    $products2 = DB::table('manual_sellers')

            ->where('car_title' , 'like', "%$query%")
            ->orWhere('make', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('model', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('manufact_year', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhere('car_body', 'like', "%$query%")

->get();
```

after making two variables i simply merged the arrays like this

```
$data = $products1->merge($products2);
```

works for me that because the method i was trying before simply was collecting arrays of arrays in one array that needed two foreach loops to render values which was a pain....

but by merging like this it combined all arrays from their parent arrays in one parent array and there i got only one foreach loop which was needed...

thanks